# Retain cycle possibility when calling a getter on a weak pointer and passing it to a method

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, retain-cycle

I've been reading up more on retain cycles all day and I'm starting to confuse myself. So I just wanted to check a couple of things. **(Just for clarification, I'm using ARC)**

So let's say I have `MyFirstClass`. `MyFirstClass` has an strongly pointed (by default) instance variable to `MyChildClass`:

```
MyChildClass *_child;
```

`MyFirstClass` also has a getter (publicly available in the .h) like so:

```
-(MyChildClass *)child
{
    return _child;
}
```

Now let's say I have another class entirely, `MySecondClass`. `MySecondClass` has a weak instance variable pointing to `MyFirstClass` like so:

```
__weak MyFirstClass *_firstClass;
```

There is a parent class that holds both `MyFirstClass` and `MySecondClass` so `MySecondClass` just has a weak reference to `MyFirstClass` so it doesn't stop the parent class from releasing it when it wants to.

`MySecondClass` also has it's own child class, strongly referenced with an instance variable too:

```
MySecondChildClass *_secondClassChild;
```

`MySecondChildClass` wants to reference `MyFirstClass`'s `MyChildClass` object.

So I guess I use a weak pointer here too, within `MySecondChildClass`:

```
__weak MyChildClass *_firstClassChild;
```

It has a custom init to set this:

```
-(id)initWithFirstClassChild:(MyChildClass *)firstClassChild
{
    if(self = [super init]){
        _firstClassChild = firstClassChild;
    }
}
```

Finally, there is a method in `MySecondClass` that creates `MySecondChildClass`:

```
-(void)setupChild
{
    _secondClassChild = [[MySecondChildClass alloc] initWithFirstClassChild:_firstClass.child];
}
```

Is this all correct? I'm 90% sure that's all fine but I'm getting confused.

What about when I'm using `_firstClass.child`, does that create a strong pointer to it? Should I be referencing `__weak` somewhere in that method call? How about during `MySecondChildClass`'s init? It has a temporary pointer to `MyChildClass` before it sets the instance variable, does that create a strong pointer I should worry about?

Any clarification would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need any weak references here.

I'm calling these objects P, A, A', B, and B' where:

```
P is an instance of your "Parent Class"
A is an instance of "MyFirstClass"
A' is an instance of "MyChildClass"
B is an instance of "MySecondClass"
B' is an instance of "MySecondChildClass"
```

So then your picture looks like this, **if** I read your question correctly:

```
  /----> A ----> A'
 /       ^       ^
P        |       |
 \       |       |
  \----> B ----> B'
```

If that picture matches what you wrote, then there is no retain cycle there and you shouldn't therefore need any of those references to be weak.

Comment: Okay great. I think I'm confusing myself. I actually also have the A' and B' pointing back to their parent for certain reasons, which I use a __weak pointer for. That would otherwise cause a retain cycle though right? When trying to remove A or B.

Comment: Yes, from the way you describe this, you would have a retain cycle if A' maintained a strong ref back to A.